# Overflow button color not changing / overflow button not visible

Tags: android, android-styles

So , I have an overflow button in my app which looks like this :

[image]

so as you can see in android studio the overflow button is visible , just like how I want it to be
but when I run the app on my phone , I do not see the overflow button , just a white background , but I am still able to use the functionality of overflow button (by tapping where the overflow button is supposed to be)

I have tried to fix this by changing overflow button color in themes.xml and also tried to fix this by manually changing the picture of overflow button using drawable ,but they do not work , I still get a white background where the overflow button is supposed to be

themes.xml looks like this :

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Chat" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#F1F1F1</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="titleTextColor">@color/black</item>


        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>

        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Any help will be appreciated

EDIT : menu.xml looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item
     android:id="@+id/settings"
     android:title="Settings"
     />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:title="Logout"
        />
</menu>
```

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"> 
<item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.Overflow.Icon</item> </style> 

<style name="ActionButton.Overflow.Icon" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow"> <item name="android:src">@mipmap/yourwanticon</item> </style> 

Hope this helps you

Comment: It does not work I still get a white background where the overflow button is supposed to be